# for a friend's birthday, a special birthday card

Tags: arithmetic

My question is particulary, my friend will celebrate 27 years (March 19, 1987) and we will offer him the game Diablo 3 : The reaper of Souls . 
So, I would write on the card all the coincidences between his birth date and the number 3 of Diablo 3 =)

He is graduate studies of Mathematics, but not me :p So can you give me help for find several coincidences between these numbers ?

On the one side, numbers of Diablo 3 : 3 and 4 maybe (D = 4)

On the other, his birth : 27 (2 and 7), 19 (2 and 9), March, 1987 ...
Ideally, I'm looking most elegants ways =)

Comment: I am not sure how this question should be taggged. I have tried ([tag:arithmetic]). If somebody can think of a more suitable tag, please, do retag this question. The tags [before migration](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/44261/revisions) (i.e., on mathematica.SE) were (algebra) and (game).

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1987_(number)

1987 is the 300th prime. That might help.

Answer (score 0):

$27=3^3$ seems mandatory here, given Diablo 3.  $3^7=3^{(3+4)}=2187$ can be useful if you can find a useful $200$ to subtract off.